# DocuSign embedded signing - how to get url of the document that contains signature?

Tags: docusignapi

Instead of getting url of the signed document in an email, we need a way to get it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, are you trying to retrieve the signed or unsigned version of the document?

In either case, I would suggest you check out a cool tool we have called [code example launchers.](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant)

If you are attempting to embed the signing ceremony in your app *before* the user interacts with it (embedded signing), you'll want to first create the envelope and then request a RecipientViewURL ([see example #1](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant/blob/master/lib/examples/eg001EmbeddedSigning.js))

If, instead, you are attempting to retrieve completed documents *after*, you'll want to call the GetEnvelopeDocuments API ([see example #7](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant/blob/master/lib/examples/eg007EnvelopeGetDoc.js))

Comment: #7 suggests how to download the document but I need url of the signed document instead of the document itself.

Comment: There is no url for the signed document, by design, due to DocuSign document security rules. Instead, please download the document and make it available as appropriate,

Comment: URLs no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for EnvelopeViews::CreateSharedRecipient - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSharedRecipient